# Mocking parameter of a void method

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose I have the following setter:

```
public void setNewPath(final String path) {
  if (StringUtils.hasText(path) && !path.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            this.newPath = path + File.separator;
        } else {
            this.newPath = path;
        }
    }
```

I'd like to mock the parameter `path` in my test method. Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you mock it? It's a string - why not just provide an appropriate string? Please give more context about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why do you want to mock the input parameter ? I would expect you to test the method with various inputs, and assert some behaviour (e.g. the setting of newPath)

Comment: I would like to know if the parameter is modified or not (either entering in the 'if' block or the 'else' block)

Comment: Just come up with some valid inputs that test both paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good problem for mocking. Under no circumstances will the parameter be modified in place, given that Strings are immutable, and though a mock could tell you if a method is called it won't let you track the value across the modifications you'd be making.

As Brian Agnew posted in the comments, "test the method with various inputs, and assert some behaviour (e.g. the setting of newPath)". Make sure that `newPath` has a getter, even if the getter is only for testing (and is documented as such).